# Probability of finding mutation

Tags: probability

The chance of finding any mutation, say 'E' is $1$ in $50000$ 'O' cells. I found $162$ such 'E' cells, how many 'O' cells did I look into?

Will it be $(1/50000) \times 162$? Or will it be $(1/50000)$ to the power $162$? In that case, what will be the answer in $10E-$ value?
I am finding it hard to compute, if I say it is $(1/50000) \times (1/50000) \times (1/50000) \ldots\  162$ times, I am not able to calculate it. Please help.
Which is the right way to estimate this number?

Answer (score 2):

The point is, $1$ in every $50000$ cells has a mutation. Hence, to find $1$ E cell, you have to look through $50000$ O cells.  Now, extend this argument.

Suppose you are looking for $2$ E cells. To find the first one, you need to look through $50000$ cells, and the to find the second one another $50000$ cells ,so in total, you had to look through $50000$ cells twice, so the answer is $50000 \times 2$ in that case.

Similarly, suppose you are looking for $3$ E cells. To find the first one, you need to look through $50000$ cells, and the to find the second one another $50000$ cells , and then to find the third one *another* $50000$ cells ,so in total, you had to look through $50000$ cells thrice, so the answer is $50000 \times 3$ in that case.

Now, if you have to find $162$ E cells, then you have to look through $50000$ cells $162$ times. Hence, the number of cells you have to look through is $162 \times 50000 = 8100000$ cells.

Reply back if you don't understand this logic.

Comment: Thank you for making it that simple. Yes, it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$P(E)=\frac{1}{50,000}=\frac{162}{162\cdot 50,000}$$